# Shell script and java parameter

Tags: java, shell, unix, command-line-arguments

I have written the script **run.sh** below for calling a java class :

```
java -cp . Main $1 $2 $3 $4
```

Here is my java class (it just displays the args) :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

This is working unless I try to pass a parameter containing a space. For example :

```
./run.sh This is "a test"
```

will display :

```
This
is
a
test
```

How could I modify my shell script and/or change my parameter syntax to pass the parameter "a test" unmodified ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
java -cp . Main "$@"
```

Comment: It might help if you explained *why* that works.  This is a pretty contrived example.  That may not be exactly what he wants to do in the end.

Answer (score 4):

You have to mask every parameter in the script as well:

```
java -cp . Main "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"
```

Now parameter 4 should be empty, and $3 should be "a test".

To verify, try:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1 "$1"
echo 2 "$2"
echo 3 "$3"
echo 4 "$4"
echo all "$@"
```

and call it

```
./params.sh This is "a test" 
1 This
2 is
3 a test
4 
all This is a test
```

Comment: The fact that parameter 4 is the empty string is annoying because the java program will receive a wrong number of parameters (4 while the user passed only 3). I think Ignacio's answer is better, thanks anyway.

Comment: @SuperChafouin: Oh, I see, my test wasn't accurate. I thought the "$@" would consume the masking, after seeing the output of my test, but I guess it is the last echo, which consumes the quotes, just like the Java program does.